# mplayer: error while loading shared libraries: libvdpau.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mplayer

I believe it happened after NVIDIA drivers installation, but not sure about it.

I've tried following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libvdpau1
```

and got this output

```
Reinstallation of libvdpau1 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
And:
sudo aptitude reinstall libvdpau1The following packages will be 
REINSTALLED:
  libvdpau1 
E: Can't find a source to download version '1.1.1-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1' of libvdpau1:amd64
E: Can't find a source to download version '1.1.1-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1' of libvdpau1:amd64
E: Internal error: couldn't generate list of packages to download
```

There is my output of `dpkg --search libvdpau.so.1`

```
libvdpau1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau.so.1
libvdpau1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau.so.1.0.0
```

Explain step by step please, what should I do in order to make it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using a symbolic link:

```
cd /usr/lib

/usr/lib$ sudo ln -s vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.304.135 libvdpau.so.1
```